# Issues with clock settings on windows

Tags: windows-7

Hello there fellow users. I have an issue where i set up clock, my laptop starts to lag crazy. I have to restart and the clock is back to default. This is caused when i try going a year ahead. There is already an issue with the clock settings that went back to 1/1/2009 when the plug is pulled out. Before i could change time without issue, then all of a sudden i could not. I am unable to access sites as such. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the time settings change when you unplug the laptop I'm pretty sure that your problem is the CMOS battery, it's dead.
You should check your laptop manual and check how to replace it. After that all your time setting problems should be gone.